# Is it possible to unload declarative classes in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, class, mapping, sqlalchemy, declarative

I’m working on a library where the user shall be able to simply declare a few classes which are automatically backed by the database. In short, somewhere hidden in the code, there is

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class LibraryBase(Base):
    # important library stuff
```

and the user should then do

```
class MyStuff(LibraryBase):
    # important personal stuff

class MyStuff_2(LibraryBase):
    # important personal stuff

mystuff = MyStuff()
Library.register(mystuff)
mystuff.changeIt() # apply some changes to the instance
Library.save(mystuff) # and save it

# same for all other classes
```

In a static environment, e.g. the user has created one file with all personal classes and imports this file, this works pretty well. All class names are fixed and SQLAlchemy knows how to map each class.

In an interactive environment, things are different: Now, there is a chance of a class being defined twice. Both classes might have different modules; but still SQLAlchemy will complain:

> SAWarning: The classname 'MyStuff' is already in the registry of this declarative base, mapped to < class 'OtherModule.MyStuff' >

Is there a way to deal with this? Can I somehow *unload* a class from its `declarative_base` so that I can exchange its definition with a new one?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.instrumentation.unregister_class(cl)
del cl._decl_class_registry[cl.__name__]
```

The first line is to prevent accidental use of your unregisted class. The second unregisters and will prevent the warning.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, And I'm not really sure this even works, but I think what you want is

`sqlalchemy.orm.instrumentation.unregister_class()`

http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/762548ff8eef/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py#l466

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use this solution.
Where library specified columns defined as mixin by `declared_attr` and target mapper created by `type` call with bases, as result I have full functional mapper.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, BigInteger, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr


Base = declarative_base()


class LibraryBase(object):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    @declared_attr
    def library_field(self):
        return Column(BigInteger)


class MyLibrary(object):

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, entity):
        tablename = entity.__tablename__
        Mapper = type('Entity_%s' % tablename, (Base, LibraryBase, entity), {
            '__tablename__': tablename,
            'id': Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True),
        })
        return Mapper

    @classmethod
    def setup(cls):
        Base.metadata.create_all()


class MyStaff(object):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable1'

    @declared_attr
    def staff_field(self):
        return Column(BigInteger)

    def mymethod(self):
        print('My method:', self)


class MyStaff2(MyStaff):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    session = Session()

    # register and install
    MyStaffMapper = MyLibrary.register(MyStaff)
    MyStaffMapper2 = MyLibrary.register(MyStaff2)
    MyLibrary.setup()

    MyStaffMapper().mymethod()
    MyStaffMapper2().mymethod()

    session.query(MyStaffMapper.library_field) \
        .filter(MyStaffMapper.staff_field != None) \
        .all()
```